# Not getting a "Save/Open file" dialog when clicking on links to files

Tags: php, html

I'm creating html links to files on my server, however when I click the links I do not get a popup window asking for Save or download dialog like this one:
[image]

I want to get that window when i click on the links.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
listDirectory(".");

function listDirectory($path) 
{     

$handle = @opendir($path);   

 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))

 {         

 if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;  
 if ( is_dir("$path/$file")) 
 {  
print ("<a href=\"$path/$file\">$path/$file</a>");   
 }  
 else  
 {  
print ("<a href=\"$path/$file\">$path/$file</a>"); 
  }     
  }     
 closedir($handle); 
  }
?>
```

Note: print ("$path/$file"); ~ works only for particular browser only ( not for IE ) and Directory download cannot be done

Comment: What do you mean by pop window ? a normal Popup ?
if so you can't do that without Javascript unfortunately, however you can print the JS from within php, this way php is the one that's responsible for displaying the popup, would that be good for you ?

Comment: PHP is a server-side technology, so it can't be used. HTML is a markup language, so it can't be used. Sorry, there are no options for you. **/Edit:** I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Oh wait I'm sorry I misread your question, you're trying to click on a link to a file and just download it, this is pretty straightforward, but can you describe what happens exactly when you click on any on the `$file/$path` anchors ?

Comment: Also what server are you running this on ? because you can simply allow directory listing and you can even bypass writing any php code at all, this is supported by most http servers.

Comment: i want directory and files listing ( recursively ).When i click on href , normal pop should come up asking "save or open the file".                                                              Currently wat is happening is i have to manually right click and save the file which is not wat i require...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to support old Browsers, you can use the [HTML5 download attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute).

If support for non-HTML5-Browsers is needed, you can use PHP to force the browser to download the file using a custom set header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=my_file.extension
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Sending the application/octet-stream content type doesn't allow the browser to display the document (e.g., if it is an iname or something else the browser can display itself).

Comment: You have to write a download script that does this. For example, map /files/filename to /files.php/filename; and let files.php write the headers folowed by the content: http://f.malte70.de/files.php.txt